# IntelliJ IDEA Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

My first time using IntelliJ IDEA, sorry if this question has been asked before but I just cannot figure it out.

I am using IntelliJ on a GitHub repo that comes with three projects and the structure like below:

[image]

CreditcardProducer is the project that I stuck to, TransactionProducer.scala is the script I need to run, however, on the right side, it shows:

[image]

As you can see, Main Class shows red and there is a warning at the bottom.

If I run it, I get error saying `Could not find or load main class`

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: I guess you're talking about the projects in https://github.com/pramoddatamantra. These are three different projects, not a single one. You should open each of them one by one by selecting their respective root directory (i.e.CreditcardProducer, for the first one). IDEA will find the pom.xml in each project and configure each project correctly.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.